# Pointing Nginx at a Port Gunicorn is Running On

Tags: linux, nginx, gunicorn

I can successfully access my app by running

`gunicorn app:app -b 0.0.0.0:8000`

and navigating to either `domainname.io:8000` or `<ipaddress>:8000`.

However, I can't seem to redirect traffic from `domainname.io` or `ipaddress`  (no port number) to this app. I created a file named `anagram` in `/etc/nginx/sites-available/anagram` with the following contents:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name domainname.io;

    location / {
            proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8000;
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    }
}
```

With the thought that the `proxy_pass` line would redirect traffic from port 80 to the port my app is running on. I then created a link to this file in the `sites-enabled` directory and ran `sudo /etc/init.d/nginx restart`. I also updated the `gunicorn` command to use the localhost address.

However, when I navigate to `domainname.io` or `ipaddress` Chrome gives me "This site is not available" instead of the expected landing page of my app.

I tried replacing the `server_name` field to the IP address of my VPS, but nothing changed. I also tried changing the ports on both the `gunicorn` command and in the nginx config, but I had the same results as using port 8000.

Comment: Having the same issue here, seems they want different ports, otherwise one can't bind to that port. Have no answer to your question yet though.

Comment: Try to add the port number to your "proxy_set_header" config like this:

proxy_set_header            Host $host:$server_port;